# Flutter how I will inject a JavaScript in webview?

Tags: flutter

In flutter I'm using package webview_flutter: ^3.0.2, here I'm trying to run a javascript in webview and get the result, My effort is like below

```
body: WebView(
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    userAgent: 'random',
    initialUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/',
    onWebViewCreated: (controller){
        this.controller = controller;
        print(controller.runJavascriptReturningResult("10 + 20"));
    },
),
```

I'm getting result

```
flutter: Instance of 'Future<String>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should await the function's result since it will return a Promise or a Future:

```
body: WebView(
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    userAgent: 'random',
    initialUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/',
    onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
        this.controller = controller;
        String? result = await controller.runJavascriptReturningResult("10 + 20");
        print(result);
    },
),
```