# How to call a JavaScript method in a Flutter WebViewWidget with the "webview_flutter" plugin?

Tags: flutter, android-webview

In Flutter I have a simple stateful widget that displays a website in fullscreen.
For that I'm using the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin.
Here's a simplified version of the widget where I removed irrelevant variables and functions. As an example the widget shows the Google website in fullscreen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebViewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WebViewScreen> createState() => _WebViewScreenState();
}

class _WebViewScreenState extends State<WebViewScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  late WebViewController webViewController = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
    ..setNavigationDelegate(
      NavigationDelegate(
        onProgress: (int progress) {},
        onPageStarted: (String url) {},
        onPageFinished: (String url) {},
        onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
        onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      ),
    )
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://www.google.com/'));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: WebViewWidget(
              controller: webViewController,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What I now want to do is to call a JavaScript function (for testing purposes let's just make it `alert('Hello World');`) right when the webview loaded (onPageFinished).
How can I achieve this?

I asked ChatGPT-4 this exact question. Its answer was to add

```
webViewController.evaluateJavascript("alert('Hello World');");
```

within the onPageFinished method. So:

```
//...
//onPageFinished: (String url) {
   webViewController.evaluateJavascript("alert('Hello World');");
//},
//...
```

But this results in a problem:

```
The method 'evaluateJavascript' isn't defined for the type 'WebViewController'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'evaluateJavascript'.
```

When I ask ChatGPT-4 about this problem it only provides answers which make no sense. I assume that has to do with the fact that ChatGPT has less knowledge about more recent developments.

I also found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71855794/flutter-how-i-will-inject-a-javascript-in-webview) but it doesn't seem right because here a "WebView" widget is used instead of the "WebViewWidget" widget that I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this library, in order to call javascript functions, you may use  webViewController.runJavaScriptReturningResult(String)

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer I've been looking for. For the sake of completeness, "String" is the JavaScript code like "alert('Hello World');" and the whole line of code can go e.g. within the onPageFinished method.

Answer (score 2):

This may help someone else, I noticed that the documentation may have a typo or it was updated recently, not sure, but here's the typo:

```
controller.runJavaScript
```

Should be:

```
controller.runJavascript
```

In the following example on [pub.dev for webview_flutter 4.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/example)

```
  Future<void> _onShowUserAgent() {
    // Send a message with the user agent string to the Toaster JavaScript channel we registered
    // with the WebView.
    return webViewController.runJavaScript(
      'Toaster.postMessage("User Agent: " + navigator.userAgent);',
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onListCookies(BuildContext context) async {
    final String cookies = await webViewController
        .runJavaScriptReturningResult('document.cookie') as String;
    if (context.mounted) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('Cookies:'),
            _getCookieList(cookies),
          ],
        ),
      ));
    }
  }

  Future<void> _onAddToCache(BuildContext context) async {
    await webViewController.runJavaScript(
      'caches.open("test_caches_entry"); localStorage["test_localStorage"] = "dummy_entry";',
    );
    if (context.mounted) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
        content: Text('Added a test entry to cache.'),
      ));
    }
  }

  Future<void> _onListCache() {
    return webViewController.runJavaScript('caches.keys()'
        // ignore: missing_whitespace_between_adjacent_strings
        '.then((cacheKeys) => JSON.stringify({"cacheKeys" : cacheKeys, "localStorage" : localStorage}))'
        '.then((caches) => Toaster.postMessage(caches))');
  }
```

Comment: I was tearing my hair out about this. Capitalisation!